# Mercurial Install centos 6.4 Python error

Tags: python, mercurial, centos, rpm

I am trying to install a merucrial repo on my VPS that has centos 6.4

I am following the tuorial at: http://www.jmedved.com/2012/06/mercurial-on-centos-6-2/

To get the an upgraded version of mercurial I am entering the command below which throws an error.

> rpm -Uvh http://pkgs.repoforge.org/mercurial/mercurial-2.2.2-1.el6.rfx.i686.rpm

Error is:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    libpython2.6.so.1.0 is needed by mercurial-2.2.2-1.el6.rfx.i686
```

I have no clue how to fix this problem. I searched on internet and I am keep trying but not successful so far.

Comment: Why don’t you use repoforge as intended? http://repoforge.org/use/

Answer (score 0):

Once again I had to dig much deeper on the internet and yet find my own answer to the question.

Use the following package instead with python 2.6 (that comes as default with Centos 6). Execute the command below and ignore the one in question.

rpm -Uvh http://pkgs.repoforge.org/mercurial/mercurial-2.2.2-1.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm

Above command should work straight away and install Mercurial 2.2

Comment: What you should have done is:
rpm -Uvh http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm  
yum --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras install mercurial